Which method to use for Laravel Collection to find a Date between two DateTime
$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('2024-03-20 00:00:00'),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    new DateTime('2024-03-28 23:59:59')
);
$suppliersInfo = OrderProduct::whereNotNull('brand')
        ->whereBetween('updated_at', ['2024-01-01 00:00:00', '2024-05-01 00:00:00' ])->get();

$labels = [];

foreach ($period as $date){
          $labels[] = $date->format('d-m-Y');  
          $dateToSearch = $date->format('Y-m-d'); 
          $orderCount = $suppliersInfo->where( 'updated_at' , $dateToSearch ) 
         ->where('brand','nestle')
         ->count();
         $data[] = $orderCount;
}

As you see from the code above, I have a date information with just date but I need to search it in the database's (postgresql) updated_at DateTime field. Because this field also has time info, I can't find the date. I can set two dates from $dateToSearch with 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 time infos and use whereBetween but I'm not sure if it's a suitable solution. Is there anything easier like we use whereDate at Eloquent?
I use $labels[] and $data[] arrays to create a javascript chart. X axis has dates and Y axis has order count and header section has brand name. Because js chart uses every data in the $labels and $data one for each, sequentially, I need to fill them with suitable data sequentially. Thats why I need to look at the database for every order if it happened in the date which I query ($period has these dates).
I have two option:
1-Query table in a loop and look for the date which I searched.
2-Take all the recors from the table and look for the date which I searched inside records.
I choose the second solution because it doesn't busy the database for every date lookup. But in this solution I can't pair the pure date info with datetime info because it has time. My solution is below
$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('2024-03-20 00:00:00'),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    new DateTime('2024-03-28 23:59:59')
);
$suppliersInfo = OrderProduct::whereNotNull('brand')
        ->whereBetween('updated_at', ['2024-01-01 00:00:00', '2024-05-01 00:00:00' ])->get();

$labels = [];

foreach ($period as $date){
          $labels[] = $date->format('d-m-Y');  
          //$dateToSearch = $date->format('Y-m-d'); 
          $startDate = $date->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'); 
          $endDate = $date->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59');
          $orderCount = $suppliersInfo->whereBetween( 'updated_at' , [ $startDate, $endDate] ) 
         ->where('brand','nestle')
         ->count();
         $data[] = $orderCount;
}

By the way I can't use DatePeriod::INCLUDE_END_DATE because of my PHP version. (8.1.2)

Please create a working demo with sample data at https://phpize.online/ so that we can demonstrate and prove the success of our recommendations with your sample data.  I feel like your process wants grouping and filtered counting in the lone eloquent query.  What is your PHP version?

I have enhanced the explanation. My PHP version is 8.1.2

No phpize.online demo for us?

I wil try to write a demo ASAP.

did you use the whereDate method ?
$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('2024-03-20 00:00:00'),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    new DateTime('2024-03-28 23:59:59')
);

$labels = [];
$data = [];


foreach ($period as $date){
    $labels[] = $date->format('d-m-Y');
    $dateToSearch = $date->format('Y-m-d');

    $orderCount = OrderProduct::whereNotNull('brand')
        ->whereDate('updated_at', $dateToSearch)
        ->where('brand', 'nestle')
        ->count();
    
    $data[] = $orderCount;


With this code you query database in every loop. IMO It's better to query once and use records from the collection.

you can use DB::raw to apply the date function to your field.
// assuming these have been validated to be a date in the "Y-m-d" format
$startDate = $request->input('start');
$endDate = $request->input('end');

// this will result in a collection of updated dates as keys and their count as values
// @var collect<string,int> $data
$data = OrderProduct::query()
  ->select([DB::raw("DATE(updated_at) AS updated_at_date"), DB::raw("COUNT(*) AS count")])
  //->whereNotNull('brand')
  ->whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE(updated_at)'), [$startDate, $endDate])
  ->where('brand', 'nestle')
  ->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE(updated_at)"))
  ->orderBy("updated_at")
  ->pluck('count', 'updated_at_date');


I allready have records in the collection. It's unneccessary to query everytime.

@FerhatNalbant what? this is the same code you have provided, but with a modified where condition to use wrap updated_at with date function. Given your code this is running only once and you don't have any records in the collection yet.

this is answering you question. If you want to count orders by date, use a group by and count.
